# Using decltype(func<T>()) to compute a type that is incomplete

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, incomplete-type

Suppose I have the following code to compute a new type based on the given one:

```
struct S1;
struct S2;

// S1 and S2 are incomplete here

template<typename> struct get_type {
    using Type = S2;
};

template<> struct get_type<int> {
    using Type = S1;
};

template<typename T> using Get_type = typename get_type<T>::Type;

struct S1 {};
struct S2 {};

void foo() {
   Get_type<int> s1;
   Get_type<long> s2;
}
```

So far so good. Suppose now that I want to use a function to do the same job with the following constraints:

1. The returned type (like `S1`) is incomplete.
2. All type computation logic should be done with `if constexpr` (in my problem `T` is pretty complicated and it is much easier to use nested `if`s than SFINAE).

This code

```
template<typename T> auto get_type() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        return S1{};
    else
        return S2{};
}

template<typename T> using Get_type = decltype(get_type<T>());
```

won't work because `S1` and `S2` are incomplete. To circumvent the problem, I can use a `type_identity` "wrapper":

```
template<class T> struct type_identity {
    using Type = T;
};

template<typename T> auto get_type() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        return type_identity<S1>{};
    else
        return type_identity<S2>{};
}

template<typename T> using Get_type = typename decltype(get_type<T>())::Type;
```

or a pointer:

```
template<typename T> auto get_type() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        return static_cast<S1*>(nullptr);
    else
        return static_cast<S2*>(nullptr);
}

template<typename T> using Get_type = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(get_type<T>())>;
```

What are the alternative ways to do it? (I would even say "better", but I'm afraid of being accused of asking an opinion-based question.)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you can beat `type_identity` here

Comment: libstdc++ type traits have recently been hardened against incomplete types: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2019-05/msg00038.html. The techniques used in this patch are likely to be of interest for you.

Comment: You can use an undefined `template<class T> T rval(T*);` and `decltype(rval(pointer_chooser<T>()))`, but I’m not sure that’s materially better.